# Bootstrap Responsive sub menu issue

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having an issue with a mobile responsive bootstrap menu. Basically the menu is meant to slide down to show the sub menu but instead it is showing as a dropdown menu and the parent menu is staying static.

Here's the problem: http://benjaminbrooksguitar.ipage.com/test/home/

Any help would be appreciated.

```
     <nav id="nav" class="navbar header2 dropdown navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="nav-container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php bloginfo('url')?>"><img class="navbrand" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/l"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
              'theme_location' => 'top_menu',
              'depth' => 2,
              'container' => false,
              'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
              'fallback_cb' => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
              'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
            );
            ?>
          </ul>
        </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the minimal code required to reproduce the problem instead of an external link.

Comment: I can post the html markup but as the menu system is reliant on bootstrap's javascript files i don't know relevant it would be.

Comment: I have a working edition of this in Bootstrap, if you could post some of your code we may be able to help out

Answer (score 0):

One thing that will get you closer is that you are missing a few CSS classes on your `<nav>` element.

```
nav id="nav" class="navbar header2 dropdown navbar-default navbar-static-top">
```

Should be switched to:

```
nav id="nav" class="navbar header2 dropdown collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse navbar-default navbar-static-top">
```

Attempt playing around with these changes and see if you can get something working. I have to run, otherwise I would look into this further. I will update you tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It hasn't made any difference other than adding the 'collapse' class seems to set the navbar to display:none when resized to a mobile display. Changing it to display:block still produces the same original issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing this bootstrap css setting

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
position: static;
float: none;
width: auto;
margin-top: 0;
background-color: transparent;
border: 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none; } }
```

Comment: thanks, but i think this is at line 4222 in the css file.